# Print reverse function

Tags: data-structures

I wrote this function to print reverse of linked list it reverses and write elements but it writes
4
3
2
1 
but I want to write it like 
4->3->2->1. what do I wrong? And I need to use minimum chars that possible.

```
void printReverse(struct node* head)
{

    if (head == NULL)
       return;

    printReverse(head->next);
    cout<<head->data<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to include "-->" in your cout statement

for eg: `cout<<head->data<<"-->";`

After calling printReverse() function use `cout<<"\b\b\b   ";` statement it will remove extra three characters from the end bcz with the help of backspace escape charcter '\b' we go back and place empty charcter there.

Below program will help you more

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<stdlib.h>  // for malloc()

struct Node
{
int val;
struct Node *next;
};
typedef struct Node node;

int main()
{
        node *start,*last,*nn,*start2=NULL;
        int tmp;

        node* makenode(int);
        void printlist(node*);
        void printReverse(node*);

        start=last=NULL;

        cout<<"Press -99 to stop the process "<<endl;
        while(1)
        {
            cout<<"enter no  :";
            cin>>tmp;
            if(tmp==-99)
            break;
            nn=makenode(tmp);
            if(start==NULL)
                start=nn;
            else
                last->next=nn;
            last=nn;
        }

cout<<"\n\nOriginal Link list  :";
printlist(start);
cout<<"\b\b\b   ";

cout<<"\n\nReverse of link list  :";
printReverse(start);
cout<<"\b\b\b   ";

return 0;

}

node* makenode(int tmp)
{
        node *nn;
        nn=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        nn->val=tmp;
        nn->next=NULL;
    return nn;
}

void printlist(node* ptr)
{
 while(ptr)
 {
     cout<<ptr->val<<"-->";
     ptr=ptr->next;
 }
}

void printReverse(node* head)
{

    if (head == NULL)
       return;

    printReverse(head->next);
    cout<<head->val<<"-->";
}
```

[Output of the above program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIr7L.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `"-->"` in `cout` statement

```
cout<<head->data<<"-->"<<endl;
```

**EDIT:**

Above mentioned solution will print like this, `4-->3-->2-->1-->`

To avoid printing `-->` after last number you need to pass two pointers in the print function, one is head and second pointer that will only point to the first node in the linklist and use an if statement to check whether head node and second node that is pointing to first node in the linklist point to the same node or not.

Try this function

```
void printReverse(struct node* head, struct node* head2)
{

    // Base case
    if (head == NULL)
       return;

    // print the list after head node
    printReverse(head->next, head2);

    // After everything else is printed, print head
    if(head->next == head2->next)
    {
       printf("%d ", head->data);
    }
    else{
        printf("%d ->", head->data);
    }

}
```

`struct node* head2 = head;` Include this statement before calling this function so that head2 is pointing towards first node.

Comment: but this time it prints like 4->3->2->1->

Comment: @rondo check my answer again. i have made some changes